# Return web page body from Spring end point

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Is it possible to return html web page as very long string from Spring endpoint? For example:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/redirect/{token}", consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
              MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE },
                  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
      public ModelAndView handleRedirectMessage(@PathVariable("token") String token,
              @RequestBody PaymentTransaction transaction, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

            String body = "<html>.....</html>";
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + body); 

  }
```

I would like to return html page body when user opens the Spring end point into the web browser.

Comment: Have you tried simply returning a `String` with the html, rather than a `ModelAndView` and a `"redirect:"` at the start?

Comment: No, in general what is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @user2478398

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/redirect/{token}",produces =  MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    public String handleRedirectMessage(@PathVariable("token") String token,
                  @RequestBody PaymentTransaction transaction, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
                 String body = "<http>.....</html>";
                return body; 

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use produce as - `produces =  MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE`

I have changed your code and you can changed it your way , this is an idea to resolved you problem

```
@PostMapping(value = "/redirect/{token}",produces =  MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    public ModelAndView handleRedirectMessage(@PathVariable("token") String token,
            @RequestBody PaymentTransaction transaction, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

          String body = "<HTML><body>Now you can redirect just do it man !!.</body></HTML>";
          return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + body); 

}
```

Comment: I get not readable exception then I open the url from the Spring endpoint.